# Question Regarding the Accuracy of my Answers

Tags: vectors

It's been a long time since I have posted on a forum like this so please bear with me if I make any mistakes with my form of questioning.

I have been trying to solve this problem below:
[image]

My answers are:

a) 2i - 3k

b) -3i + 4k

c) 8i + 6k & 4i + 3k

Logically and with what I know of vectors so far, I think my answers are correct, however, I am unsure because the answers in the answer key are different even though it does mention that other answers are possible. The answers in the answer key are as follows:

a) 0.60i - 0.80k

b) 0.60i + 0.80k

c) 0.80i + 0.60k & -0.80i - 0.60k

I want to know if my answers are correct and if they are not, why are they not correct?

Appreciate any help. P.S. This is not any form of homework help, I am simply solving this in my free time lol.

Comment: Do you know what a unit vector is?

Comment: You answer for a) is not correct, aside from the vector magnitude issue.

Comment: @Sloan Ahh, I thought unit vector meant a vector in it's unit/component form but clearly I was wrong. Thanks! Now, I understand where I was wrong.

Comment: @user3257842 $\sqrt{2^2 + 3^2} \ne 5$